# Sort mongoose documents by dynamic subdocument field

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to sort a mongoose model by a subdocument with a dynamic field.

When I hardcode the subdocument field (`'July2022'`) **it works**:

```js
      const leaderboardSpots = await this.LeaderboardSpotModel.find()
        .sort({ 'estimatedProfit.July2022.profit': 1 })
```

But I need the time frame (`'July2022'`) to be dynamic so it can be set to other months/years.

### What I tried

**1. I tried to create a sort object**

```js
      const timeFrame = 'July2022';

      const sort = { estimatedProfit: {} };
      sort.estimatedProfit[timeFrame] = { profit: 1 };

      const leaderboardSpots = await this.LeaderboardSpotModel.find( )
        .sort(sort)
```

But this gave me:
**Error Message:**

```
Invalid sort value: { estimatedProfit: [object Object] }
```

**2. I tried using a template string**

```js
.sort({ `estimatedProfit.${timeFrame}.profit`: 1 });
```

This gave me `SyntaxError: Unexpected template string`

**Example Document**

```
{
  user:"627d3f2e4a43de00048dcbba",
  estimatedProfit:
    { July2022:
       {profit: 93525}
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

putting brackets around the template string worked. I think this is Es6 syntax.

```js
.sort({ [`estimatedProfit.${timeFrame}.profit`]: 1 });
```